# Variables that are defined in Livewire component not access in the blade html code (Custom HTML Tags )

Tags: html, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-livewire, custom-tags

```
    <div x-data="{ open: @entangle('showEditt') }" id="welcoEmeDiv">
        <x-modal-lg confirmText="{{ __('Update') }}" action="update">
            <p class="text-xl font-semibold">{{ __('Update Product') }}</p>
            <x-input title="{{ __('Name') }}" name="name" />
            <div class="grid grid-cols-2 space-x-4">
                <div>
                    <x-select title="{{ __('Barcode Type') }}" name="barcode_type" :options="['code_128', 'code_39', 'ean8', 'ean13', 'upc']" selected="{{ !empty($selectedModell) ? $selectedModell->barcode_type : 'code_128' }}" />
                    <x-input-error message="{{ $errors->first('barcode_type') }}" />
                </div>
                <x-input title="{{ __('Barcode') }}" name="barcode" />
```

This is html code i cannot access the attribute $selectedModell->barcode_type inside the html code

```
public $selectedModell;
public function openModal($id)
{

$this->selectedModell = Product::find($id);
$this->showEditt=true;

}
```

This function open the view and get the object selectedModell.
I can't access to the object selectedModell in the blade why ?!!

Comment: In your blade, what is `@dd($selectedModell)`?

Comment: @dd($selectedModell) in blade give the result but inside the <x-select  ..........>      not  access to the  $selectedModell

Comment: Right, its a component, so you can't use it inside unless you pass it in, like `:selectedModell=$selectedModell` on the `x-select`.

Comment: Give this error : ParseError
syntax error, unexpected '<' (View: C:\wamp64\www\Market\resources\views\livewire\stock-ins.blade.php)                            when use this                                                                    :selected="{{ !empty($selectedModell) ? $selectedModell->barcode_type : 'code_128' }}" />                              and add      selected="{{ $selectedModell }}" in the select.

Comment: Please can you explain more about this : :selectedModell=$selectedModell on the x-select –

Comment: Read the Laravel docs, https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#passing-data-to-components